# Security considerations when adding instance url to remote sites

Tags: security

Can someone describe the possible security implications of adding the URL for your salesforce instance as a remote site?

Understand this allows users to call certain rest apis tooling/metadata.  Just curious what type of possible risks this presents..  Thank you!

Comment: to be clear.. I'm adding the user's salesforce instance URL not an external server/service url.

Answer (score 1):

Any app that you install could have code that uses the API. That code could do Bad Things beyond what it could normally do without API access (particularly metadata, tooling API access). Fortunately, most apps you'll ever install are vetted by the Security Review Process, so there's minimal risk. Adding any salesforce.com URL to Remote Sites is usually risk-free, while adding non-salesforce.com URLs suggests that your data can be sent to those URLs (so make sure they're trusted).

Answer (score 0):

There is no doubt with the security issues, things depend on the logic or code that you are using under that exposed URL, sometime because of our code only we end up loosing our data, this is the only concern should be taken care of while using API and +Salesforce Limits.

Hope I am getting you right

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure that there is no confusion --- adding a remote site URL value of foo.my.salesforce.com to a salesforce instance bar.my.salesforce.com does not risk foo but bar. Bar is the one protected with a remote site setting policy, not foo, because an attacker can always make a callout to foo whenever they want. The remote site settings are to prevent code within bar from calling out to untrusted sites. Whitelisting the set of sites that can be the targets of callouts from bar helps defend against things like referral leakage, data leakage in URL params of bar data.

If you control both sites or trust both sites then there is not a risk at all.